# Is there such a thing as an optional deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm having difficultly figuring out how to write this block of code...

```
function myFunction(x,y,z) {
  // do some stuff here (code block A)

  // then some stuff here (code block B)

  // but... 
  if (y == 73) { // y isn't always 73...
    // I need more data from the server before I can complete this function
    $.getJSON("data.php", {y: 73, z: z}, function(data) { ... });
  }

  // and finally some other code down here (code block C)

  // And done!
  $.post("data.php", {data: someVariable}, callbackFx);
}
```

So the conceptual problem I'm having is that I have code I want to execute (code block C) after I realize I need to get more data from the server for the given inputs. It doesn't happen all the time, but I essentially want to pause execution. And we all know Synchronous AJAX is a crime, punishable by flogging from the Javascript gods.

At first I figured code block C should just go in its own function, but it gets messy because there are many dependencies in code block C on the rest of the code above.

So I thought about using deferred/promise, but how can I execute code as a promise if the AJAX doesn't always necessarily happen?

```
if (y == 73) {
  var deferred = $.getJSON("data.php", {y: 73, z: z}, function(data) { ... });
  deferred.always(function() { ... });
}
else {
  // that function in the deferred never gets called
}
```

The closest to a "good answer" as I could think of was the following (but I have no idea if its actually a "good answer")...

```
var codeBlockC = function() { ... };

if (y == 73) {
  var deferred = $.getJSON("data.php", {y: 73, z: z}, function(data) { ... });
  deferred.always(codeBlockC);
}
else {
  codeBlockC();
}
```

Then there are issues with scoping and closures and stuff. Any ideas? Do I just need to completely reorganize how I'm going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler approach is to place the functionality of *code block C* in a nested function. JavaScript has lexical scope, so all of the needed data will still be available to it.

For example:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z) {
  // do some stuff here (code block A)

  // then some stuff here (code block B)

  var codeBlockC = function() {
      // code in here can access all variables from code blocks A and B
      // everything after the potential Ajax call needs to be in here

      // and finally some other code down here (code block C)

      // And done!
      $.post("data.php", {data: someVariable}, callbackFx);
  };

  // but... 
  if (y == 73) { // y isn't always 73...
    // I need more data from the server before I can complete this function
    $.getJSON("data.php", {y: 73, z: z}, function(data) { 
        codeBlockC(); // execute as callback
    });
  } else {
      codeBlockC(); // execute immediately
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as the alternative in the original question?

Comment: @Pointy -Similar, I guess, except my point is that there's no need for jQuery's deferred objects. JavaScript's scoping rules get the job done.

Comment: Perhaps the use of deferred in this case is superfluous. If I can have a clean solution w/o it I'll take that route. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could always start off with a dummy promise:

```
var def = { always: function(f) { f(); } };
if (whatever) {
  def = $.get( ... whatever ... );
}

def.always(function() {
  $.post( ... whatever ... );
}
```

I guess that's what your basic question was, so the answer is "yes" :-)  Just make your own.  Of course you could define it as a global service if you feel like it's going to happen a lot.

I guess you could also start with a legit constructed "Deferred" object that you immediately resolve.

Comment: +1 to the immediately resolved Deferred. I use this approach when I'm in the described situation.

Answer (score 1):

Though I think I like the simplicity of lwburk's answer better, you can also create your own method that works as a deferred method.  This gives some more flexibility with more complicated situations. See [jQuery Deferred Object for more info](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) on setting this up but here it is with your example:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z) {
    var deferredFunction;

    // do some stuff here (code block A)

    // then some stuff here (code block B)

     //define your own function that is deferred
    deferredFunction = function () { 
        var defer = $.Deferred(); 

        if (y == 73) {
            $.getJSON("data.php", {y: 73, z: z}, function(data) { 

                //your code... 

                defer.resolve();
            });
        } else {
            defer.resolve();
        }

        return defer.promise();
    }

    //now execute the your function and when it resolves execute the rest of the code
    deferredFunction().then(function () {

         // and finally some other code down here (code block C)

         // And done!
         $.post("data.php", {data: someVariable}, callbackFx);
    });
}
```